# Python: Appending a list by other lists

Tags: python, list, append

I want to append the lists "b", "c" and "d" to my list "a". Then i want to print the single lists in each line. My expected output is:

```
[(4, 'Blue'), (3, 'Red'), (4, 'Red')]
[(2, 'Green'), (4, 'Green'), (1, 'Yellow')]
[(1, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue'), (3, 'Green')]
[(2, 'Blue'), (1, 'Red'), (4, 'Yellow')]
```

My current code is:

```
a = [(4, 'Blue'), (3, 'Red'), (4, 'Red')]
b = [(2, 'Green'), (4, 'Green'), (1, 'Yellow')]
c = [(1, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue'), (3, 'Green')]
d = [(2, 'Blue'), (1, 'Red'), (4, 'Yellow')]

a.append(b)
a.append(c)
a.append(d)

for x in a:
    print(x)
```

My current output is:

```
(4, 'Blue')
(3, 'Red')
(4, 'Red')
[(2, 'Green'), (4, 'Green'), (1, 'Yellow')]
[(1, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue'), (3, 'Green')]
[(2, 'Blue'), (1, 'Red'), (4, 'Yellow')]
```

As you see the first 3 lines of output are separated and not together. How can I change this so that it appears according to my expected output?

Comment: Do you want a list of lists or a list of elements?

Comment: You can use `a.extend([b, c, d])` instead of appending 3 times.

Comment: Don't you just need `e = [a,b,c,d]`?

Comment: Sorry about the initial duplicate marking. I misread your intended output.

Comment: You don't need to use `.append` at all, as @Sayse points out. But you can easily fix the code by simply understanding what happened. Think: *why* does `a.append(b)` give you the initial elements of `a`, followed by `b` as a single element? Given that the appending of `b` puts the correct thing into your output, can you think of a way to put `a` into your output correctly? (By using `.append(a)` on something, right?) If you were to do that, what starting point would you need to have instead? (it would have to be a separate thing, right, Which is empty? Yeah?)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code adds each b/c/d list as an **element**. So you have a list with 6 element, the last 3 of which are lists.

```
[(4, 'Blue'),
 (3, 'Red'),
 (4, 'Red'),
 [(2, 'Green'), (4, 'Green'), (1, 'Yellow')],
 [(1, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue'), (3, 'Green')],
 [(2, 'Blue'), (1, 'Red'), (4, 'Yellow')]]
```

I think what you want to do is use a larger container. (WHY? I don't know, I guess it's a dummy example part of a larger code).

```
a = [(4, 'Blue'), (3, 'Red'), (4, 'Red')]
b = [(2, 'Green'), (4, 'Green'), (1, 'Yellow')]
c = [(1, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue'), (3, 'Green')]
d = [(2, 'Blue'), (1, 'Red'), (4, 'Yellow')]

out = [a]
out.append(b)
out.append(c)
out.append(d)
# or out = [a,b,c,d]
# or out.extend([b,c,d])

for x in out:
    print(x)
```

output:

```
[(4, 'Blue'), (3, 'Red'), (4, 'Red')]
[(2, 'Green'), (4, 'Green'), (1, 'Yellow')]
[(1, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue'), (3, 'Green')]
[(2, 'Blue'), (1, 'Red'), (4, 'Yellow')]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are appending `b`, `c`, and `d` as elements to `a`, which means that the original elements of `a` are not nested in a list like that of `b`, `c`, and `d`.

To package the elements of `a` into a list first, we can do `a = [a]` before the appending.

So our code now becomes:

```py
a = [(4, 'Blue'), (3, 'Red'), (4, 'Red')]
b = [(2, 'Green'), (4, 'Green'), (1, 'Yellow')]
c = [(1, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue'), (3, 'Green')]
d = [(2, 'Blue'), (1, 'Red'), (4, 'Yellow')]

a = [a]
a.append(b)
a.append(c)
a.append(d)

for x in a:
    print(x)
```

**Output:**

```
(4, 'Blue'), (3, 'Red'), (4, 'Red')]
[(2, 'Green'), (4, 'Green'), (1, 'Yellow')]
[(1, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue'), (3, 'Green')]
[(2, 'Blue'), (1, 'Red'), (4, 'Yellow')]
```

Answer (score -3):

> My expected output should be:

```
[(4, 'Blue'), (3, 'Red'), (4, 'Red')]
[(2, 'Green'), (4, 'Green'), (1, 'Yellow')]
[(1, 'Green'), (3, 'Blue'), (3, 'Green')]
[(2, 'Blue'), (1, 'Red'), (4, 'Yellow')]
```

That's not a valid list. It's just four different lists.

Comment: Taramon is referring to the output as generated by the `for` loop, not the list itself

Comment: It is valid, the op is printing the lists

Comment: The output comes from iterating over a list and `print`ing each element. Clearly what OP is saying is that the resulting data should be a list of lists, but the problem is that it instead contains some elements from the first list mixed with the other lists.